# sendmessage with shift, control, alt key combinations

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, keyboard

I'm trying to send Key combinations like <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, etc to a specific window.  I am able to send F8 by itself by posing a `WM_KEYDOWN`, then a `WM_KEYUP` and specifing `(int)System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F8` as the `wParam`, but can't figure out how to do it with the shift key.  I've tried ORing it with `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.SHIFT` as well as `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.SHIFTKEY` but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there some other way?

Note that I can't use `SendInput` or possibly because they don't take window handles, and my window may not be in the foreground.  Any suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You must use [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) or `SendInput` to send modifier keys to another application because of the way windows handles modifier keys (fun, yes?).  I think both may require the other application to have focus to work correctly.

Just sending a series of keydowns / keyups as if you were pushing and holding the modifier keys doesn't (or, at least, didn't last I tried it) work since most applications poll for those keys separately instead of listening for messages about them.  I suppose if you control the source for both applications this may work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by @jnm2, injected [SetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646314.aspx) worked for me for an inactive window.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The only supported way to inject input is via [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). The system does not offer a way to inject input for a specific thread or window.

Since there is no way to generate input given the additional requirements, faking input is a dead-end. That leaves you with two options:

1. Communicate through a dedicated automation interface if the application has one (MS Office applications, for example, provide an automation interface).
2. Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) as a system-supplied virtualization of the UI with the ability to automate it.

And those are the only supported ways for automating a UI. Everything else is just going to be a hack.